# Setting Binary Transfer mode

Tags: linux, perl, ftp, file-transfer

My Perl script below is very basic. It goes and copies a .zip file located on one server and transfers it to another server.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
my $remotehost ="XXXXXX";
my $remotepath = "/USA/Fusion_Keyword_Reports";
my $remoteuser = "XXXXXXX";
my $remotepass = "XXXXXXX";

my $inputfile ="/fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/list8.txt";
my $remotefile1;
#my $DIR="/fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM";
open (FILEIN, "<", $inputfile) or die "can't open list8 file";


while (my $line =<FILEIN>) {
if ($line =~ m /Keywords-Report(.*?)/i && $line !~ m/Keywords-Report-loopback/i) {
  print $line;
$remotefile1 =$line;
last;
}
}
close FILEIN;

print "remotefile $remotefile1\n";


my $DIR1="/fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/$remotefile1";

my $cmd= "ftp -in";


my $ftp_command  = "open $remotehost
                  user $remoteuser $remotepass
                  cd $remotepath
                  asc
                  get $remotefile1
                   bye
                ";

  open (CMD, "|$cmd");
  print CMD $ftp_command;
close (CMD);


exit(0);
```

When I run the script it does work but I get an error and the file that gets transferred is corrupted as a result.

```
226 Transfer complete.
WARNING! 40682 bare linefeeds received in ASCII mode.
File may not have transferred correctly.
```

I did some reading and I think I need to set the transfer mode to binary.  However I am really not sure how to do that in my script.  Additionally, I am not sure that is the right solution either.

I would really appreciate your thoughts about this error.  If setting the transfer mode to Binary will fix this problem can you please show me where I would do that?

Comment: I don't have access to man pages, but from past experience with `ftp`, changing your param `asc` to `bin` will probably do it. If not, try just a plain `b`. Good luck.

Comment: Shellter is right. Not setting the mode to ascii (removing the `asc` line) is a good start, setting binary (change `asc` to `bin`) even better. Also, consider using the Net::FTP module (http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html), which will provide much better error handling.

Comment: Just changing the asc to binary spelled out totally fixed it!  Thanks for the help Guntram!

Answer (score 2):

```
my $ftp_command  = "open $remotehost
              user $remoteuser $remotepass
              cd $remotepath
              binary
              get $remotefile1
               bye
            ";
```